# Python reading and saving html file

Tags: python, html

I was asked to help in a small project and, as part of my tasks, I need to read some HTML files and extract some sections and then save the file. I am having a problem which I think is related to encoding and I am lost. The problem is that when I read the file a lot of weird characters appear and make it harder to analyze also tables become unreadable.

```
for file in file_list:  # Process each file
    f=open(file, "r")
    fileread=f.read()
    text= str(fileread)
    text_file = open(FolderTarget + os.path.basename(file), "w")
    text_file.write(text)
    text_file.close()
```

From the example above I have deleted all the parsing and extraction bits as they are irrelevant for my problem. You can see in the link below my original file (left) and the output (right). Link here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w92874ukj9j1vsf/Screenshot.jpg?dl=0

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to post images here, not Dropbox links. Also, provide output as a test when possible.

Comment: you can use BeautifulSoup module in Python, which helps you extract information from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding and experience, the html files are in xml format.
I previously used [xml.etree.ElementTree — The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)
to parse xml file. It is a very useful tool, you can easily get the label you need and further modify them and save it to a new file

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
all_parameter = ET.parse("../../modelparameter/plant/{}.xml".format(name)) # read the parameter file from xml file
```